# Query Elasticsearch with Python script: set size

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm running a script that queries an Elasticsearch index, like this:

```
es.search(index=source_index, body=query, size=50)
```

I get my results, but there's also the following deprecation warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Received 'size' via a specific parameter in the presence of a 'body' parameter, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead, use only 'body' or only specific paremeters.
```

Can someone point out the correct way to define the size parameter? I'm running version: 8.12.0 of the Python Client for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid passing the `size` parameter separately when you're already providing a body parameter. Instead, you should include the `size` parameter within the body of your `Elasticsearch` query.

```
query = {
  "size": 50,  # This is where you define the size parameter now
  "query": {
    // Your query goes here
  }
}

# Now you only need to pass the `query` body
es.search(index=source_index, body=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the size:value to your query parameter.

```
query = {
        "size": 5000
    }  
result = es.search(body=query, index='source_index')
```